# PowerBI: How to get distinct count for a column in a table, while grouping for many columns separately

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with multiple date columns, and a single label column, as shown by following code

```
Data = DATATABLE (
"Date1", DATETIME,
"Date2", DATETIME,
"Label", STRING,
{
    { "2020-01-01","2020-01-02", "A" },
    { "2020-01-01","2020-01-01", "A" },
    { "2020-01-01","2020-01-02", "B" },
    { "2020-01-01","2020-01-01", "D" },
    { "2020-01-01","2020-01-02", "E" },
    { "2020-01-02","2020-01-01", "A" },
    { "2020-01-02","2020-01-02", "B" },
    { "2020-01-02","2020-01-01", "C" }
}
)
```

I want to plot a chart of count of distinct labels for each day, when considering date1, as well as when considering date2. These need to be in same plot, as a clustered bar plot, as shown below. This means I need to get the values on a new date column.

The expected result looks like this,

```
Date                | value1    | value2
---------------------------------
1/1/2020 12:00:00 AM |  4       |   3 |
1/2/2020 12:00:00 AM |  3       |   3 |
```

[image: clustered bar plot]

## Current Solution:

1. I am creating two different tables for each of the counts, as follows

   ```
    Date1_Count = 
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        ALL ( Data[Date1] ),
        "Count",
            CALCULATE (
                DISTINCTCOUNT ( Data[Label] )
            )
    )
   ```

   and

   ```
    Date2_Count = 
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        ALL ( Data[Date2] ),
        "Count",
            CALCULATE (
                DISTINCTCOUNT ( Data[Label] )
            )
    )
   ```
2. Then I create a third table with dates as such,

   ```
    Final_Counts = CALENDAR("2020-01-01", "2020-01-04")
   ```
3. Next, I add relationship between the three dates, viz. Date1_Count table, Date2_Count table, and Final_Counts table
4. Finally, I combine the data using `RELATED` function as follows

   ```
    value1 = RELATED(Date1_Count[Count])
    value2 = RELATED(Date2_Count[Count])
   ```

## Question

Is there a simpler solution that does not require creating one table per date column? The current method is not scalable to many date columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only have a handful of date columns, you just need a single date dimension table and one measure per date column.

Define a date table to use on the x-axis (no relationships to other tables):

```
DimDate = CALENDAR("2020-01-01", "2020-01-04")
```

Then define measures that match the various date columns to the date table:

```
value1 =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( Data[Label] ),
    Data[Date1] IN VALUES ( DimDate[Date] )
)
```

and

```
value2 =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( Data[Label] ),
    Data[Date2] IN VALUES ( DimDate[Date] )
)
```

[image: Result]

---

If you have more than a handful of `DateN` columns, then you'd probably be best served to reshape your data where you unpivot all those columns.

For just the two you have the data would look like

[image: Unpivot]

In this case, you use `Unpivot[Column]` as the Legend and only need a single measure:

```
value = 
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( Unpivot[Label] ),
    Unpivot[Date] IN VALUES ( DimDate[Date] )
)
```

This gives a similar looking result:

[image: One measure]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to obtain the Final_Counts calculated table in one step, using ADDCOLUMNS to iterate over Data[Date1], and then calculating Value1 as the DISTINCTCOUNT over the Data table filtered on the currently iterated Date1.

This work thanks to the CALCULATE statement that triggers a context transition.

Obtaining the Value2 requires to create a new filter context over Date2 using the currently iterated Date1.

First we save the current Date1 in a variable to be used inside CALCULATE in the filter expression on Date2.

We also need REMOVEFILTERS( Data ) to remove the filter context over Date1 set by the context transition.

```
Final_Counts =
ADDCOLUMNS(
    ALL( Data[Date1] ),
    "Value1",
        CALCULATE(
            DISTINCTCOUNT( Data[Label] )
        ),
    "Value2",
        VAR CurrentDate = Data[Date1]
        RETURN
            CALCULATE(
                DISTINCTCOUNT( Data[Label] ),
                REMOVEFILTERS( Data ),
                Data[Date2] = CurrentDate
            )
)
```